# Simplest linear programming solver?

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming

In a programming contest I've encountered a problem which is for sure a linear programming problem. I know quite a lot about LP (the simplex method, its exponential complexity, interior point methods, their polynomial complexity, etc.), yet I stumbled upon it. What is the simpliest algorithm for linear programming by means of implementation? Is there an algorithm I can implement in Python or C++ under tough time limitations?

Comment: You are not allowed to use solvers API? (GLPK, CPLEX, GUROBI,...)

Comment: Simplex/revised simplex are easy for coding. I assume you do not care about maximum efficiency. Though simplex worst case for Datzig rule might be exponential or even endless, those examples are artificial and never happens for real-life models.

Comment: @newbie I guess I'm not.

Comment: The part about implementing in any particular language is off-topic, here, but I think the rest of the question is fine.

Comment: Define "simple".

Comment: @Raphael the one I can implement quickly without a book or specific library and also not demanding hours of debugging.

Comment: Such a thing may not exist. Also, it makes the answer relative to your skill level in several dimensions, which we don't know anything about. Closing this as subjective for now; if you can come up with a question that admits an objective answer, please edit and flag for reopening!